# Kafka Consumer partition mapping

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have 100 consumers in same group listening to same topic and 100 partition. So as per the documentation each consumer should only listen to one partition since there are 100 consumers and 100 partitions. I produce the message to kafka using a key. So some message with the same key should go in the same partition and should always be consumed by the same consumer in the group. But in my case multiple messages with the same key are consumed multiple consumers randomly. Any way to do that all messages from a partition are consumed by only one specific consumer in the group. I do not want to explicitly assign partition to consumers.

Answer (score 1):

1. Verify that your message partitioning is working as expected from the producer side
2. If you have 100 consumers using same consumer group id for a 100 partitions topic , each consumer will get exactly 1 partition to consume from.

Comment: As Liju John said, most likely the issue is that the upstream application(s) that write to the input topic don't properly partition the messages they write.  Also, are you sure that the written messagen actually have a key?  If the message key is `null`, then messages will be randomly sent across partitions.